# One way ping. Windows 7 and windows 8.1

Tags: networking, connection, ping

server w/ windows 7 can ping the other PC w/ windows 8 but the windows 8 can't receive a reply from the server when I try to ping.

[image]

Comment: did you turned off firewall on each computer ?

Comment: already did on both computer

Comment: are you in a domain environment or in a home network ?

Comment: no im not in a domain, im connected in a home network

Answer (score 0):

[image]

try this hope this works then fine for you

Comment: type cmd ipconfig /flushdns and try it again if it´s not working restart both computers